# ggplot doesn't sort values like it supposed to

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I always like to sort my charts in the dataframe instead of in ggplot with the `reorder()` function this tactic works most of the time but sometimes, even if I won't change anything, the charts order chages to an alphabetic order...

Dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

most_used_words %>%
    arrange(desc(times_used)) %>%
    top_n(5)

 A tibble: 20 x 2
         word times_used
        <chr>      <int>
 1       news        148
 2       fake        147
 3     people        133
 4    country         95
 5        tax         92

most_used_words %>%
  arrange(desc(times_used)) %>%
  top_n(5) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = word, y = times_used)) +
    geom_col(fill = "#03A9F4") +
    coord_flip()
```

While the following code sorts the times_used variable correctly in ggplot...

```
most_used_words_candidate %>%
      arrange(desc(times_used)) %>%
      top_n(5)

    # A tibble: 20 x 2
              word times_used
            <fctr>      <int>
 1 realdonaldtrump        965
 2           trump        762
 3          people        489
 4         hillary        435
 5         america        350

most_used_words_candidate %>%
  arrange(desc(times_used)) %>%
  top_n(5) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = word, y = times_used)) +
    geom_col(fill = "#03A9F4") +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: I don't see you using `reorder()` here at all which is what you need. The order of rows in the data.frame itself doesn't matter at all. It's the order of the levels of the factor that determine plotting order and they easiest way to change that is with `reorder()`. I don't understand what you are really asking here. You seem to already know the correct answer.

Comment: But the weird thing is that the second plot does sort the data correctly. But they both consist of the same code.

Comment: The `word` variable in your two examples are different variable types.  In the first it is a character and in the second it is a factor.  My guess is that the levels in the factor in the second example are already in the desired order.  To get the same behavior in the first example, convert to a factor and set the level order prior to plotting.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't work either thanks for answering though, I'll just make sure I use `reorder()`

Answer (score 2):

@aosmith is right. `ggplot` expects the inputs as factors with levels. That is the reason your second code is properly ordered. If you try this

```
df$word  <- factor(df$word , levels=unique(df$word ))
```

and re-plot the 1st code. It will order by alphabetical order like you prefer.

Some [resource here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html)